# How to wipe data in a table each time you save to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, restsharp

I've currently built a Visual Studio C# project that saves API data into a database through Entity Framework. Everything works fine, but I've noticed each time I run the application, the data is duplicated in the table.

I have to restart it every now and then since there is new data that needs storing, but I was thinking is there an easy way or even just a way that wipes the table before you save the data to the DB each time you run the application?

Here is the code I'm running at the moment.

```
public static void getAllRequestData()
{
    var client = new RestClient("[My API URL]");
    var request = new RestRequest();
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string rawResponse = response.Content;
        AllRequests.Rootobject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllRequests.Rootobject>(rawResponse);

        using (var db = new TransitionContext())
        {
            db.RequestDetails.AddRange(result.Operation.Details);
            db.SaveChanges();
        } //Utilising EF to save data to the DB
    }
} //Method that calls and stores API data
```

This method is used to get API data, deserialize it, then save it to a Db.

```
public class TransitionContext : DbContext
{
    private const string connectionString = @"[My Server]";

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public DbSet<AllRequests.Detail> RequestDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AllRequests.Detail>().HasKey(r => r.Id);
    }
}
```

This is my Entity Framework DbContext that scaffolds the table and maps the data to each column.

This all works, but what would I have to include in my code for it to stop duplicating data each time I run the project? Currently, I get just over 1000 rows in my table each time I run the project, eventually, it gets clogged. I want it to be the same data each time I run it except with a few additions that are added each week.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Traditionally, you _Insert_ new data into a database.  If someone makes a change you _Update_ the existing data.  Do your tables have primary keys or any _Unique_ constraints?

Comment: Yeah my table has a primary key, I had to create a new primary key since the API data that I'm obtaining doesn't have a primary key so I just made one in my project. 

The thing is though, I noticed that every time I run the project, it keeps duplicating the same data (but on a different Id of course). So if I run the project 4 times, I will have 4 of the same rows for each data but with a different Id.

Comment: So, you have a primary key, and it's an identity column.  Since you have a PK, you can update the data and when you call `SaveChanges` on the context, EF will update rows corresponding to the data you updated. Consider a table with `ID` and `Name` columns.  It has three rows, with incrementing IDs and names _Alice_, _Bob_ and _Carol_.  If you read everything in, change _Bob_'s name to _Robert_ and call `SaveChanges`, the table should be updated-Presto.

Comment: I mean you could fetch the table, remove the rows, then add the new ones... Or match on some index and update them instead.

Comment: But that doesn't stop the data from duplicating? Every time I hit SaveChanges the data duplicates. And I sort of know why, it's because of the fake Id that I made for the API that just increments on every new row. But I had to make it for the sake of the table. 

However, I have found a way to do this by deleting the data and adding new data on each process with "db.RequestDetails.RemoveRange(db.RequestDetails)" thanks to one of the answers here. That solution does work even if it's not completely ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this issue will depend on how the API works. If the data is returned in a sequence that doesn't change between calls, then you can remember the index of the last object saved in the database and next time save only fields that have a higher index. However if order isn't maintained between calls then you will be left having to manually compare objects to check for duplicates, which is not very time efficient but will be better than nothing. The thing is that second option won't work reliably if each item returned isn't unique. In that case the only viable method would be to clear the table entirely and reinsert everything. You can empty the table by calling `db.RequestDetails.RemoveRange(db.RequestDetails)`. This might even be faster than the comparation method anyways.

Comment: Thank you, this works. 

The ID's keep adding up but I don't care that much as long as the data is reset and it's not duplicating the same rows each time I run it. Appreciate the solution!

Comment: @KyleAT I'm happy I could help :) I'd only like to add that if it's possible you should consider the method where you save the last index from the api, since it will probably be the most efficient. If you're stuck with clearing the table however, `db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sqlStringToClearTheTable)` might be a bit better than what I suggested earlier, but the exact parameter will depend on the sql you are using.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll have a look at this, the more efficiency the better but I'm just happy it works.

Comment: I've tried the executeSqlRaw solution instead, thank you it's better. I would prefer to do the first method you mentioned but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm manually adding new data each time I run the solution. I would like for it to only add new rows rather than deleting. But obviously, if I don't delete, they duplicate instead.

Comment: All API calls do share an ID by the way, and they should be the same so they can be memorised.